# Centre text inside a Cardview - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, center, android-cardview

I'm currently using a Card View inside a recycler and the text is left-alligned despite my efforts.

Here is the Book Item Layout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookTitleTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the recycler itself.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bookRecycler" />
```

This is the current output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7miYi.png)

As you can see the text is not centered.

I tried using layout gravity to center the text which didn't work.
I also tried using a constraint layout on the text view and using constraints to center the text without any luck.

android:layout_gravity = "center" has already been attempted.

Any advice on what I'm overlooking would be great.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `android:gravity="center"` for `LinearLayout` and you are good to go

I see your `LinearLayout` have only one child and no special attributes, so you can even remove whole `LinearLayout` - place `TextView` straight inside `CardView`, which `extends FrameLayout`. For centering childs inside `FrameLayout` you may also use `android:gravity="center"` for parent and/or `android:layout_gravity="center"` for child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
            ... rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:gravity="center"` is the correct code, instead of `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work either, I already tested that, forgot to mention that. Thank you.

Comment: If TextView `android:layout_width="match_parent"` then `android:gravity="center"` works